# error 0xc00220e6 system scheduler

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a SSIS package that in turn run other internal packages. The Scheduler does not run because of it. (Error 0xc00220e6 )

The .BAT file you have configured as follows:

```
 @echo off  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /FILE
  "C:\Users\dramigo\documents\visual studio
  2010\projects\Retiros\Retiros\RetirosFenix.dtsx"/CHECKPOINTING OFF
 /REPORTING EWCDI  echo Terminado........ exit
```

Comment: This link might help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fb3aca38-14aa-4d29-9935-1a4e0afd5a60/error-executing-ssis-packages-from-agent?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: I do not have permissions to the SQL Server. Is there another way ?

Comment: Make sure that the account that the process runs under have the correct permissions.

Comment: I belong to an organization and I can not access these permissions. Is there any other way to solve the problem ?

Comment: Can you have one of your administrators check it for you?